# How to open a seperate child window on a click to parent window silverlight?

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, web-applications, silverlight-5.0

I am new to c# and i create a project in silverlight-5 and i chose "ASP.NET web application" while selecting the project. which has GUI coding in xml and behind i code in c# to handle the events. The project on running opens Internet explorer and shows the GUI there.(It is to explain you what kind a project i have created, I am not using WPF application, there are lot of samples for WPF but less for silverlight using xml).

I have to create a GUI which will consists of a button intially (suppose **"File"** ). On clicking "file" it must shows 3 buttons.**"Browse","save","close"**. GUI must be like this http://prntscr.com/35qlf3 (Like on click to "file" there are is a window that opened so the same way it must open a window containing these 3 buttons and then on clicking these 3 buttons must open another window where i have some text boxes and buttons).

Whereas on further click to **"Browse"** will open a window on same Internet explorer(don't open new IE window) where i will have a button to **"Browse"** a file and will further browse the file on click to it (I already have the code for browsing but have no idea to create an interface of Parent-Child buttons like this).

And there simiral kind of functioning  associated with all other 2 buttons clicks as well(I mean they will  also open a window on their click in the same place and on the same Internet explorer window).

Any ideas how to achieve it ?

**Any link or piece of code is most appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

Make use of child Windows in Silverlight.This how you open child window from Main Page in Silverlight,

```
        var ChildWindow1 = new ChildWindow();
        ChildWindow1.Show();
```

Comment: @Sajeetharam Thanks but , Error 1 The type or namespace name 'YourChildWindowName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I mean what option should i select to create a child window

Comment: @user234839 sorry I modified the answer

Comment: One more question may i create further buttons on this window ? How to do that any link or Idea ?

Comment: @Sajeentharan Thanks Bhai, But can i do using xml ?(I think not,please correct if i am wrong). So how to create button in c# on this window ? that would be child to this window i guess ?

Comment: Just drag and drop the button from the toolbox to the child window

Comment: Actually my first view is this http://prntscr.com/35qu59 and on button click event of "Browse" click i have created that window, So i am not able to see that window in "View Designer" because it this window must be generated on button click to "Browse" on the given link. Am i still able to add buttons on this child window. The code you suggested, That i have written in my button click event of "Browse" button.

Comment: you are still not able to undersatnd what i mean to say. The child window i have created by writting c# code on button click event of ""Browse" button, so it is not visible at "View designer", Now problem is how to add the buttons on it if it is not visible ? (its not in xml it's in c#).

Comment: Just have a Grid, and add the buttons dynamically inside the Grid of the ChildWindow

Comment: Any link or piece of code for help. Because Grid is created in xml not in c# and suppose if i created a grid, and put button on it then how this grid will be linked with button click event of  "Browse" click because this grid will have it's own click event.